# Deploying Yolov5 to azure

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-functions, object-detection, yolov5

How to deploy Custom trained YOLOV5 model to azure using azure functions?
I couldn’t find any online resources

Complete Scenario:

There is a sharepoint app where user will upload the videos, once the new video is uploaded, it should trigger the flow to azure function, this azure function should be able to predict the objects in the frame with the custom trained yolov5 model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not sure about the Deployment of **YOLO5** in **Azure Function.**

Follow the below steps, it will work for any **ML model**
using **Azure Function**

#### Prerequisites:

1. Install Azure CLI
2. Install Azure Function Core Tools

#### 1. Create and test Azure function locally

Using CLI create a python function

```py
_# Create and activate an environment_  
python3 -m venv .venv  
source .venv/bin/activate_
# Create a FunctionApp Project Locally_  
func init --worker-runtime python_
# Create a Function_  
func new --name <FunctionName> --template "HTTP trigger" --authlevel anonymous
```

Edit the`__init__.py` file for your business logic to modify your model.

Add the required packages in `requirement.txt`. After that **install** the packages using

```py
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Test your function locally. using `func start`

#### 2. Create the Required Resources for your Project on Azure

#### 3. Deploy the function to Azure

Deploy  local project code to the Function App created on Azure, using

```py
func azure functionapp publish **<FuncitonAPP Name>**
```

Refer  [Build and Deploy your NLP model as a Microservice on Azure](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-steps-to-build-and-deploy-your-nlp-model-as-a-microservice-on-azure-426ca77c66df)